# Changing from List to ArrayList removes the error "List is an abstract and can not be instantiated?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, abstract-data-type

Well, I'm new to `List` I've always worked with `Arrays`, now I'm writing a program where I cannot tell the size of the array before it's creation so I'm using `List`. The thing is that I've a method that returns a List of none repeating digits.

**Here is my method:**

```
public static List<Integer> arrayOfNoneRepeatingDigits(int limit) {

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        boolean ignore = false;
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j/=10){
            if(ignore == true) break;
            for(int k = j/10; k > 0; k/=10){
                if(j%10 == k%10){
                    ignore = true;
                    break;                        
                    }                    
                }               
            }
        if(ignore == false)list.add(i);                
        }    
return list;    
}
```

First my method datatype was an Array but after I changed it to List this line of code gave an error:

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
```

I've searched online and It turned out that I should replace List with ArrayList. I did it and the error is gone now but I don't know why.

Comment: [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, not a concrete class.

Comment: In addition to your main question about `List` interface, can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve with your program? Or give an example of input and expected result. It seems that your code can be improved in several ways. Of course, if you are interested in learning and improving.

Comment: @Aivean Sure, that's why ask questions! Here is what I'm trying to achieve. http://www.devbattles.com/en/sand/post-1284-Five+programming+problems+every+Software+Engineer+should+be+able+to+solve+in+less+than+1+hour . check out the 4rt problem I've found it very interesting but please do not write the answer I'm new to Java but trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian thank you for clarification, I'll not spoil the solution. However I wonder how it's related to the code in your question. If I'm not mistaken, your code tries to find all numbers in the range that don't have repeating digits. It seems that the original problem (at least the solution that I have in mind) doesn't require such subroutine.

Comment: @Aivean I'm solving the 5th one My mistake!

Comment: @HaroutTatarian oh, I see. However it's still unclear why do you need this subroutine. Is it possible that you missed **in this order** in the line `between the numbers 1, 2, ..., 9 (in this order)`? Nevertheless, I hope I'm not too intrusive. I'm sure you'll eventually solve this problem, maybe even with some non-canonical way.

Comment: @Aivean No that's absolutely fine. I'll be glad if you give me a little hint.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian well, as far as I can see, it's some variant of [brute force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) (finding all possible solutions implies that). For this type of problems the most tricky part is the implementation itself. There are some idiomatic ways how to implement brute force. Most popular, probably, is recursion.

Comment: @Aivean Thank you, I'll let you know when I solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces cannot be instantiated, so no `new List<Integer>` stuff. Interfaces's methods don't have implementations. The implementations of those methods are in the subclasses. `ArrayList` is one of the subclasses of `List` so that's why you can use your first code snippet.

If you write `new List<Integer>`, it doesn't make sense. Because `List`'s methods don't have implementations so when you call the `add` method, how would the compiler know what implementation is in the method?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
```

doesn't make sense since you're trying to directly instantiate an *interface*, something that is not concrete and thus something that you can't do unless you create an anonymous inner class with the instantiation, something that you really **don't** want to do. The best solution: stick with the ArrayList for the concrete implementation (or LinkedList depending on your requirements). e.g.,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Out of curiosity, what motivated you to make this change when you already had working code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! and about your question I didn't understand what change you are talking about.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian: the change is that you already had `new ArrayList<>()`, which worked but tried to use the non-functioning `new List<>()`. Why?

Comment: No, I first used 'new List<>()' then I've changed it after searching online.

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface. It means there is no attribute in List, and methods are declared but not defined. So, there is not enough information to instantiate it and an error occurs. This happens same when you try to instantiate an object of an abstract class.

You can declare an object of interface/abstract class, but you cannot instantiate it. So you have two choices.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer();
((ArrayList)list).method(); 
//cast it into ArrayList. 
//If you try to cast a wrong class, then the error will be printed out.
```

This way need extra casting. Else, you can declare with ArrayList also.

```
ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Why the cast: `((ArrayList)list).method();`? What would make that necessary since you'll be using only methods of the List interface?

Comment: There are some methods like toArray <--it is not delcared in List or any other parent classes. Methods from List class is containsAll, equals, hashCode. This is a description of ArrayList class.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: OK, I'll buy that. 1+ to counteract some down-voter (not sure why the down-vote).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll explain why downvote. This answer will confuse the newbie. As the rule of thumb it's preferable to work with interfaces when possible. So it's perfectly fine to have list instantiated as `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` and then work with it as with interface. In rare cases when it's **really** necessary to work with concrete implementation, such as `ArrayList` it's **way** better to declare it as `ArrayList` instead of casting on access.